# How to dynamically set the directory for user-specified libraries

Tags: perl

I have some fairly complex libraries that interconnect with each other to do some work, and while they mostly run on our servers, they're connecting to some high-performance servers to crunch numbers.

On our servers, the line is ...

```
 use lib '/home/ourgroup/lib' ;
 use HomeGrown::Code ':all' ;
```

On the high-performance cluster, it's more like ...

```
use lib '/scratch/ourgroup/lib' ;
use HomeGrown::Code ':all' ;
```

For the programs that use the modules, that's a reasonably easy thing to set, but I would like to not have to make server-specific changes in the code base. I'd rather be able to copy the directory as-is. So, how do I tell my modules to use my library dir without hard-coding it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we're going with.

```
use lib '/home/ourgroup/lib' ;
use lib '/scratch/ourgroup/lib' ;
```

If /home/ourgroup/lib doesn't exist on one machine, so be it. If /scratch/ourgroup/lib doesn't exist on the other, so be it. It doesn't complain, so that's what we're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you do this by having the `PERL5LIB` environment variable set differently on different machines. Yes, it's not a pure-Perl solution, but it has to be done only once per server, not once per deployment.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that, but that makes a whole lot of sense. Thank you. Testing it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a module that detects the environment and includes the correct directories for for you.

To use it, just do:

```
use VarLogRant::FindLibs; 
use Stuff;
```

And to write the module:

```
package VarLogRant::Findlibs;

sub select_lib_dirs {

    my @libs;

    push @libs, '/home/ourgroup/libs' if need_home();
    push @libs, '/scratch/ourgroup/libs' if need_scratch();

    # Any other magical logic you want.

}

# It is critical that use lib comes AFTER the functions are defined.
use lib select_lib_dirs();

1;
```

Comment: Thing is, unless VarLogRant::FindLibs is in the same directory as the application, or someplace listed in @INC, you have to do the same mess as with Stuff. two 'use lib' lines seems like a simpler way to do it. until I have to port this to my ninth machine type.

Comment: @VarLogRant, If you package this module as a CPAN-style library and install it as part of your normal Perl deploy, it will be everywhere you need it.

Comment: I have no authority to do that on someone else's cluster.

Comment: @VarLogRant then pick one common place on all systems and put the file there.  Maybe this strategy won't work for you, but it has worked well for me.  Set the environment like so: PER5LIB=~varlogrant/commonperl or maybe compile a wrapper around perl that sets the enivonment or adds a `-I/common/perl/libs` to the command line, and use that as your project interpreter.